# I may not be very tall, but I can bring a downfall

Tags: riddle

> I may not be very tall
>       But I can bring a downfall
>       I am not one but many
>       We are man's enemy
>       We treasure man's waste
>       And we steal it in a haste
>       At points, we have killed many
>       But we aren't as capable anymore
>       There is a spark that kills
>       We are the distributors
>       I think I've told you enough of myself
>       So, who are we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Answer:

> Are you rats?

I may not be very tall
But I can bring a downfall

> Rats can spread disease.

I am not one but many
We are man's enemy

> Rats gather in packs of thousands, and pretty much everyone hates rats. They are abominations.

We treasure man's waste
And we steal it in a haste

> Rats eat our trash and steal our food from us.

At points, we have killed many

> Black Plague

But we aren't as capable anymore

> Thanks to sanitation measures in the last century

There is a spark that kills
We are the distributors

> They distributed the black death everywhere.

---

I'll post a slightly different answer than Simon's, are you

> Bacteria?

I may not be very tall
But I can bring a downfall

> The  black plague

I am not one but many

> Bacteria form in millions

We are man's enemy

> Again, the black plague

We treasure man's waste
And we steal it in a haste

> For example, bacteria eat waste in our intestines.

At points, we have killed many
But we aren't as capable anymore

> Thanks to antibiotics!

Comment: Same thing, close but not quite

Comment: There is a clue I could give you but that would give it away

Comment: The clue is in the poem

Comment: Yes, 15 minute rule though

Comment: @Duck Any hints on where the clue hidden in the poem is at?

Comment: The bacteria is the spark the rats are the disributors

Comment: Okay, that's what I figured.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a

> Virus

I may not be very tall

But I can bring a downfall

I am not one but many

We are man's enemy

> Viruses are microscopic, and can kill many. Viruses also tend to come in droves, plaguing a population

We treasure man's waste

And we steal it in a haste

> Viruses flourish in waste and bacteria

At points, we have killed many

But we aren't as capable anymore

> Before medicine, viruses wiped out populations.

Comment: Very close, but not quite

Comment: The keyword: distributors

Answer (score 1):

It is

> Insects

I may not be very tall

> No matter the size, insects are not tall

But I can bring a downfall

> Insects can ruin civilizations (Locusts)

I am not one but many

> Insects are seldom alone

We are man's enemy

> Insects are natural enemies of humans

We treasure man's waste

> Flies swarm around trashcans and feces

And we steal it in a haste

> It doesn't take very long for you to find insects around waste

At points, we have killed many

> Mosquitos in particular by giving malaria

But we aren't as capable anymore

> Modern insect repellents and tools keep them in check (at least more than before)

There is a spark that kills

> Literally a bug zapper

We are the distributors

> Insects are primary carriers of disease

I think I've told you enough of myself

So, who are we?

> INSECTS

Comment: Sorry, but it is rats, it fits great though

Comment: What about the line we are not as capable as was before

Comment: I put an explanation to that one. There is a ton of research into curing and treating the diseases carried, and to eliminate the carriers as well with great success.
What was the meaning behind the "Spark" line?

Comment: The bacteria is the spark the rats are the carriers